# parsley.js not displaying error messages in french

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I've got Parsley.js installed and working correctly (dead easy) however I am unable to get it to display error messages in French. I've tried [both methods detailed in the documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-installation-localization) But error message continue to display in English.

I've checked the console and there are no errors, I can also load the language file directly in the browser so it is there.

My current code is:

```
  <script src="/js/parsley/i18n/en.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/parsley/i18n/fr.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/parsley/parsley.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.ParsleyValidator.setLocale('fr');
  </script>
```

Please advise.

Comment: did you add jquery.js ? 
Parsley relies on jQuery (>= 1.8), and it would need to be included before including Parsley.

Comment: @SebriZouhaier is probably right. Your code seems to work as it is. You can take a look [at this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcba9psb/), where your code works correctly. If you have any issue, post a jsfiddle.

Comment: I've got jQuery 1.11.1 - tested with 1.8.0 and no change English only.

Comment: @CreateSean Do you have javascript errors? Are you sure the locale files are being loaded ?

Comment: No js errors and yes all locale files are loaded, I can see them in the inspector.

Answer (score 3):

I was also unable to make it work by following the instructions on the parsley.js page.

This is what worked for me, since as of 11/18/2015 following the documentation on the parsley page still doesnt work.

1- Put First the parsley js and then the localization file (from https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/tree/master/src/i18n):

```
<script src="parsley.min.js"></script>
<script src="i18n/es.js"></script>
```

2- Edit the localization file: comment the 'import', and add 'window.' before each of the 2 js instructions. example:

```
//import Parsley from 'parsley';

window.Parsley.addMessages('es', {
  defaultMessage: "Este valor parece ser inválido.",
  type: {
    email:        "Este valor debe ser un correo válido.",
    url:          "Este valor debe ser una URL válida.",
    number:       "Este valor debe ser un número válido.",
    integer:      "Este valor debe ser un número válido.",
    digits:       "Este valor debe ser un dígito válido.",
    alphanum:     "Este valor debe ser alfanumérico."
  },
  notblank:       "Este valor no debe estar en blanco.",
  required:       "Este valor es requerido.",
  pattern:        "Este valor es incorrecto.",
  min:            "Este valor no debe ser menor que %s.",
  max:            "Este valor no debe ser mayor que %s.",
  range:          "Este valor debe estar entre %s y %s.",
  minlength:      "Este valor es muy corto. La longitud mínima es de %s caracteres.",
  maxlength:      "Este valor es muy largo. La longitud máxima es de %s caracteres.",
  length:         "La longitud de este valor debe estar entre %s y %s caracteres.",
  mincheck:       "Debe seleccionar al menos %s opciones.",
  maxcheck:       "Debe seleccionar %s opciones o menos.",
  check:          "Debe seleccionar entre %s y %s opciones.",
  equalto:        "Este valor debe ser idéntico."
});

window.Parsley.setLocale('es');
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsley relies on jQuery (>= 1.8), and it would need to be included before including Parsley.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone see this and search for answer:

I could fix this Problem for me by adding "$( document ).ready(function() {}" around the code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  Parsley.addMessages('fr', {
    defaultMessage: "Cette valeur semble non valide.",
    type: {
      email:        "Cette valeur n'est pas une adresse email valide.",
      url:          "Cette valeur n'est pas une URL valide.",
      number:       "Cette valeur doit être un nombre.",
      integer:      "Cette valeur doit être un entier.",
      digits:       "Cette valeur doit être numérique.",
      alphanum:     "Cette valeur doit être alphanumérique."
    },
    notblank:       "Cette valeur ne peut pas être vide.",
    required:       "Ce champ est requis.",
    pattern:        "Cette valeur semble non valide.",
    min:            "Cette valeur ne doit pas être inférieure à %s.",
    max:            "Cette valeur ne doit pas excéder %s.",
    range:          "Cette valeur doit être comprise entre %s et %s.",
    minlength:      "Cette chaîne est trop courte. Elle doit avoir au minimum %s caractères.",
    maxlength:      "Cette chaîne est trop longue. Elle doit avoir au maximum %s caractères.",
    length:         "Cette valeur doit contenir entre %s et %s caractères.",
    mincheck:       "Vous devez sélectionner au moins %s choix.",
    maxcheck:       "Vous devez sélectionner %s choix maximum.",
    check:          "Vous devez sélectionner entre %s et %s choix.",
    equalto:        "Cette valeur devrait être identique."
  });

  Parsley.setLocale('fr');
});
```